# How can I prevent my civilian dwarves from drinking/eating from the military stockpiles?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a military training room which is off a corridor which branches off near the entrance to my base. To maximize training time, I have tables in the room, with food and drink stockpiles next to them. The problem is, because my main food/drink stockpiles and tables are much deeper in the mountain, any dwarf that is outside or near the entrance goes to the military stockpile when they get hungry/thirsty.

I've tried setting the corridor and the room to restricted, and bumped the cost up to 100, but apparently they ignore pathing costs when getting food/drink, so it does nothing. What can I do to make it so only the military dwarves can use those stockpiles and tables, while still allowing civilians to refill the stockpiles?

Comment: By restricted I take it you mean burrows?

Comment: @Canageek No, I set the traffic level to restricted. I don't want to prevent the civilians from accessing it entirely, because I need them to be able to refill the stockpile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that currently there isn't one. When hungry or thirsty, dorfs *will* make a beeline to whatever source of food or booze is closest, weighed by preference for type of food (they'll go for prepared meals if there are any available before they eat something raw, and will walk a little further for their preferred type of food or booze if it's there to eat) **even if there are enemies or hideous monsters in between them and the snack**.

"Urist McDolt cancels eat: Interrupted by Goblin Pikeman."

[Seconds pass while Urist McDolt runs away from the goblin and gets out of sight]

"Urist McDolt cancels eat: Interrupted by Goblin Swordsman."

[repeat, until]

"Urist McDolt has starved to death."

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Hm.

Comment: Generally death by goblins will occur before a dwarf has the time to starve to death.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to create a locked door or drawbridge between your military section and the rest of the fortress.

Restrict civilians to a burrow outside the military area and your soldiers to a burrow within the military area. Then lock the door or raise the drawbridge, and un-restrict everyone again.

As long as your military have everything they need in their section they should be ok in their area.

You will run into an issue resupplying your food and drink stockpiles, so you will need to grant access to other dwarves from time to time when supplies run out.

Comment: That might work, although I'm sure I'd forget about it and my military would starve to death. Or go berserk, which would be bad, considering they're all Adamantine armed and armored swordsdwarves, except for the leader, who's wielding an artifact quality Adamantine battleaxe :D

Comment: As an addendum, add a farm and still and a Military Farmer/Booze Maker to keep the military stocked...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Anyway an easy trick would be to place a little stockpile halfway between the barracks and the rest of the fortress, or the outside. That would act as a "buffer" and prevent people to eat/drink too much from military stockpiles.

Comment: One of the problems with them going to the military stockpile is that they then waste time constantly refilling it. A buffer stockpile would have the same issue.

Comment: And is that bad? Haulers have to be kept busy or they will become sad.

Comment: Oh, I've got plenty of stone that needs hauled.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make traffic designations at the entrance to the barracks. Your military dwarves will go in because it is the only way to get to their barracks, and your civilians will restock the food for the same reason, but unless they are inside the barracks, they will avoid it like the plague.

Comment: Please re-read the question. As I said, I did that, and it didn't work, and I know why it didn't work, so I'm looking for other options.